# SVN Create physical copy for new branch (using dev and main site in 1 repo)

Tags: svn, version-control, subdomain, versioning, subversive

I been giving a svn repo https://somedomain.com/svn/website/

To changes files on on the active site I commit changes to /svn/website/trunk which is linked to `~/web/www`

Now I have been given subdomain dev.somedomain.com location on disk `~/web/dev` I have been told to use tags/branches to upload files into dev folder be after reading the manual I have no clue how I should do this

I gues I have to link https://somedomain.com/svn/website/branches/dev to `~/web/dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's about right.  It sounds like you already have a dev branch in Subversion at ^/branches/dev.  How do changes in ^/trunk make it to the ~/web/www folder?  It could be that there's a Subversion working copy in that directory on disk.  In that case you can use the same strategy to populate the ~/web/dev folder.

Comment: Thanks i got it to work using a svn co in web/dev directory and using svn switch in that directory set correct branches thanks :-)